# Arduino Uno r3.. avrdude error while uploading

Tags: arduino

[image]

I recently bought a genuine Arduino Uno r3 .

As soon as I plugged it in it showed me the device name as 'ATmega16u2 DFU'.. but after a lot of google searches, I burned some hex files onto it and now the device is read in the COM ports in the computer as Communication Port 3, if I install specific drivers for it (.inf files) under the device manager it comes Arduino Uno r3..

The problem is when I try to uploadthe code it says (The RX Led flashes 3 times but then nothing happens..)

```
Binary sketch size: 444 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)

Estimated used SRAM memory: 9 bytes (of a 2048 byte maximum)
avrdude.exe: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

I already checked that I am selecting the correct COM and BOARD from the IDE. Installed the board with tons of diferent drivers... ( I have win7 x32).

Do you think this is some driver related issue, defective board or something else ?

Comment: Try contacting Arduino. Since it is a genuine board, you should get support for free. Try updating all your software and get all important updates.

Comment: There is a huge step of driver installation, in case, you have to install old drivers. That requires turning digital signature off, if it is windows 7. Also, in the IDE,you need to select the board, from the listed ones.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to go into the Arduino IDE preferences and switch on "show verbose output during upload". This in turn allows for much more precise error analysis.